# Trying to make a reverse circular singly linked list where each node is added at the front of the list but all the succeeding nodes are lost

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

Made a program in C for a reversed circular singly linked list in which each node should be added to the front of the list but for some reason all the succeeding nodes are lost in the process. Can't figure out if it's a logical flaw or some error/typo in the writing of the code.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *start, *p;
    int n;
    printf("Enter length of list: ");
    scanf(" %i", &n);
    start = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter data: ");
        scanf(" %i", &p->data);
        if (start == NULL)
        {
            p->next = start;
            start = p;
        }
        else
        {
            p->next = start->next;
            start = p;
        }
    }
    p = start;
    printf("List entered is: ");
    for (p = start; p->next != start; p = p->next)
    {
        printf("%i\t", p->data);
    }
    printf("%i", p->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p->next = start->next;` looks wrong. It should be `p->next = start;`if you think about what `start` points to (and how the next line modifies `start`)

Comment: If you're adding to the front of the list, you don't need to check if there's any nodes or not. ```p->next = start; start = p;``` works either way, as long as ```start``` is NULL whenever the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `p->next = NULL` for the first allocated `p`.
And dereferencing `p` equal to `NULL` in `p->next` is *Undefined Behavior*. So anything can happen.

Now the fix
You need to keep a reference to the last element on the list to set it's `next` to the newly created node `p`. Let's name is `end`.

At the initial step just form a pico-circular list (`p->next = p`) and left `start` and `end` point to it.

With each iteration make a newly allocated `p` a new start, update the `end->next` to point to the `p`.

The inner allocation loop can be rewritten as:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter data: ");
        scanf(" %i", &p->data);
    if (start) {
        p->next = start;
        end->next = p;
        start = p;
    } else {
        p->next = p;
        start = end = p;
    }
  }
```